# Ausubel (2004) auction, any implementation?

Tags: reference-request, auctions

I'm looking for an implementation of the ascending-bid auction introduced in his [2004 AER paper](http://ausubel.com/auction-papers/efficient-ascending-auction-aer.pdf). More specifically, a market using this framework which either

- has been reviewed by other scholars or
- has available data.

Or, on the contrary, an explanation of why this auction format is not broadly in use.